# Адаптивная верстка флекс бокса

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть две колонки (в одной текст, в другой картинка) и они расположены в одну строчку на экране. На `1920x1080` всё хорошо, но при уменьшении экрана:

[image: две куклы]

```css
containerWithiTwoRow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

columCAR {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
}

.rowInColumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.backgroundRow {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(/images/rigth.jpg);
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerWithiTwoRow">
  <div class="columCAR">
    <div class="rowInColumn">
      <h3 id="miniTitle"> текст </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="rowInColumn">
      <p class="p7"> текст </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rowInColumn">
      <ul>
        <li> <img class="mini1" src="/images/like.png"> текст </li>
        <li><img class="mini1" src="/images/chat.png"> текст </li>
        <li><img class="mini1" src="/images/spical.png"> текст </li>
        <li><img class="mini1" src="/images/credit.png"> текст </li>
        <li><img class="mini1" src="/images/chat.png"> текст </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columCAR"> (это второй элемент с картинкой на против)
    <div class="backgroundRow"> <img class="mini" src="/images/rigth.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не являюсь веб-разработчиком но когда-то пытался и могу вставить свои 5 копеек. Вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbnAKjjlgc4&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81) очень хорошо объясняется адаптивная верстка. Так же, у вас css неправильно написан. Вы обращаетесь к классам `containerWithiTwoRow` и `columnCAR` не по правилам css (должны были через точку)

Answer (score -1):

У вас в CSS containerWithiTwoRow и columCAR вызываются не через точку

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).